# I Want To Download All Data From Data Table But Its Currently Downloading The Current Page Data I Want To Download For All Pages

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax

```
 {
     extend: 'excel',
     exportOptions: {
         modifier: {
             pages: 'all'
         },
         columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14],
         format: {
             header: function (data, column, row) {
                 return data.split('<')[0];
             }
         }
     }
 },
```

I Want To Download All Data From All The Pages But This Code Only Downloading Current Page Data